# How to get "execution time for each line of code" for my program?

Tags: c, linux

I just used `gprof` to analyze my program. I wanted to see what functions were consuming the most CPU time. However, now I would like to analyze my program in a different way. I want to see what LINES of the code that consume the most CPU time. At first, I read that `gprof` could do that, but I couldn't find the right option for it.
Now, I found `gcov`. However, the third-party program I am trying to execute has no "`./configure`" so I could not apply the "`./configure --enable-gcov`".

My question is simple. Does anyone know how to get execution time for each line of code for my program?
(I prefer suggestions with `gprof`, because I found its output to be very easy to read and understand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**oprofile** is probably, as suggested by Anthony Blake, the best answer.

However, a trick to force a compiler, or a compiler flag (such as `-pg` for `gprof` profiling), when compiling an `autoconf`-ed software, could be

```
CC='gcc -pg' ./configure
```

or

```
CFLAGS='-pg' ./configure
```

This is also useful for some newer modes of compilation. For instance, *gcc 4.6* provides *link time optimization* with the  `-flto` flag passed at *compilation* and at *linking*; to enable it, I often do

```
CC='gcc-4.6 -flto' ./configure
```

For a program not autoconf-ed but still built with a reasonable `Makefile` you might edit that `Makefile` or try

```
make CC='gcc -pg'
```

or

```
make CC='gcc -flto'
```

It usually (but not always) work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, the third-party code I got doesn't have a ./configure with it... : (

Comment: I added a suggestion for reasonable `make`-based builds.

Answer (score 4):

I think oprofile is what you are looking for. It does statistical based sampling, and gives you an approximate indication of how much time is spent executing each line of code, both at the C level of abstraction, and at the assembler code level.

As well as simply profiling the relative number of cycles spent at each line, you can also instrument for other events like cache misses and pipeline stalls.

Best of all: you don't need to do special builds for profiling, all you need to do is enable debug symbols.

Here is a good introduction to oprofile: http://people.redhat.com/wcohen/Oprofile.pdf

Comment: Oprofile isn't installed on our sever, and I don't have authority to install it. Is there any other ways to do the line-by-line thingy?

Comment: Tools like oprofile require access to the performance counter registers -- so you are best running the analysis on your own machine or one you have super user access. Failing that, you might have to try and negotiate some access with your system administrators.

Comment: "perf" is an alternative to oprofile that doesn't require root access to use, though it's available only in relatively recent kernels (since 2.6.31 or such).

Answer (score 1):

If your program isn't taking too long to execute, [Valgrind/Callgrind](http://valgrind.org) + [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) + [compiling with debugging turned on (-g)] is one of the best methods of how to tell where a program is spending time while it is running in user mode.

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./program
kcachegrind callgrind.out.12345
```

The program should have a stable IPC (instructions per clock) in the parts that you want to optimize.

A drawback is that Valgrind cannot be used to measure I/O latency or to profile kernel space. Also, it's usability with programming languages which are using a toolchain incompatible with the C/C++ toolchain is limited.

In case Callgrind's instrumentation of the whole program takes too much time to execute, there are macros `CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION` and `CALLGRIND_STOP_INSTRUMENTATION`.

In some cases, Valgrind requires libraries with debug information (such as `/usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.14.1.so.debug`), so you may want to install Linux packages providing the debug info files or to recompile libraries with debugging turned on.